# Is there a method to check the homogeneity of variance of a single time series?

Tags: time-series, variance, heteroscedasticity

I have a data frame with prices/dates, is there a method that checks if the variance is homogeneous during all the series? I know there are many test like fligner.test, bartlett.test but I need to pass to those methods few groups....I don't have groups I have only one series and I need to know if the variance is constant.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have several prices for a given date?

Comment: Is this a time series, in which you wish to check if the variance remains constant over time?

Comment: @ocram, no ONE price and ONE date fro about 700 days.

Comment: @onestop, Exactly, That's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a test for **homoskedasticity**. I haven't need to use this myself yet, so I can't offer much in-depth advice, but the [wikipedia page on homoskedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity) lists a couple of tests, including the **Breusch–Pagan test**, which assumes normality in the data, the **Koenker–Basset test** which generalises the Breusch–Pagan test for non-normal data.

the [`bptest`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/lmtest/html/bptest.html) function in the `lmtest` R package implements the both tests (set `studentize=true` for the Koenker–Basset test). Looks like it's only for linear models though, so it might not work for your data.

There's a few interesting questions about these test on this site. Check out charlie's answer on [Why does the Breusch-Pagan test fail?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/why-does-the-breusch-pagan-test-fail) in particular.